# Your requirements.txt is invalid. AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

i am new to aws and django. I was tryinh to upload my code to aws elastic beanstalk using code commit while i am getting the following error

> 2020/03/12 13:42:30.200017 [ERROR] Command timed out after 300 seconds
>
> 2020/03/12 13:42:30.202535 [ERROR] Command /bin/sh [-c python3 -m pipenv install -r requirements.txt --skip-lock] failed with error signal: killed
>
> 2020/03/12 13:42:30.204812 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [SetUpPythonEnvironment]. Stop running the command.
>
> Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh [-c python3 -m pipenv install -r requirements.txt --skip-lock] failed with error signal: killed
>
> 2020/03/12 13:42:30.204825 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
>   2020/03/12 13:42:30.210383 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}
>
> 2020/03/12 13:42:30.211588 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

Comment: How about including your `requirements.txt` file in your question?

Comment: Did you try to recursively pip install your `requirements.txt` in local machine ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VQQuFhfOGGIwelz7gAjJXIJ6LyzGLGHQAs46d05xuoo/edit?usp=sharing        **this is the link to the contents of requirements.txt**

Comment: how to recursively install pip requremnts in local machine??

Comment: What platform version are you using? Could you include exact reproduction steps including the ebcli commands you used?